# Какими способами можно запретить/разрешить чтения файла?

Tags: nginx, permissions, redhat

Система: Redhat 7.5

Мне нужно создать новый хост для nginx'а.

Подключаюсь под обычным пользователем, по ssh загружаю базовый шаблон конфига, кладу его в папку рядом с дефолтным конфигом. При перезагрузке nginx ругается на то, что он не может открыть файл на чтение нового конфига.

Владелец и группа у обоих файлов одинакая - root. Права одинаковые. Даже 777 пробовал ставить - бесполезно.

Решил проблему просто копированием дефольного конфига и перенес содержимое моего конфига в дефолтный.

Т.е получается я могу только плодить файлы и изменять их содержимое, а создавать новые сам не могу, nginx орет что ему не хватает прав на чтение. Как такое может быть?

Может помимо прав, владельца файла и группы есть еще какие нибудь параметры?

Comment: Возможно включены apparmor/selinux. Пробовали класть файл в одну из имеющихся подпапок (sites-enabled или conf.d, их наличие зависит от пакета) ?

Comment: да, я как раз свой конфиг клал в папку conf.d.

Comment: А что конкретно пишет nginx?

Answer (score 1):

А что с SELinux?

Выполните команду: `getenforce`.

Если ответ будет Enforcing, значит SELinux включен. В этом случае надо будет его настроить, но если желания разбираться с ним нет или безопасность не так важна, то можно его просто отключить. Выполните команду:

`# sed -i s/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=disabled/ /etc/selinux/config`

Изменения вступят в силу после перезагрузки. Чтобы отключить SELinux на текущую сессию, выполните: `setenforce 0`